# In Python why GraphQL Enum values displayed as null?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

```
Django: 2.0.6
graphene: 2.1.2
graphene-django: 2.0.0
```

I have the following code:

```
class SWLangChoice(Enum):
    PHP = "PHP"
    PY = "Python"


SWLangChoiceEnum = graphene.Enum.from_enum(SWLangChoice)


class LangChoiceType(graphene.ObjectType):
    lang = graphene.Field(SWLangChoiceEnum)


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    langs = graphene.Field(LangChoiceType)

    def resolve_langs(self, info):
        return SWLangChoiceEnum
```

Initially SWLangChoice is a vanilla Enum object. So I converted it to SWLangChoiceEnum and created type LangChoiceType. In GraphiQL I can see the keys of this Enum (though they marked as values).
But when I request this Enum I see:

```
{
  "data": {
    "langs": {
      "lang": null
    }
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to show the values of the enum `SWLangChoiceEnum` in the query `langs` ?

Answer (score 3):

I am also not sure what part of the enum you are trying to return, but here's some minimal modification to your code that accomplishes both

```py
class SWLangChoice(enum.Enum):
    PHP = "PHP"
    PY = "Python"

# SWLangChoiceEnum = graphene.Enum.from_enum(SWLangChoice)

class LangChoiceType(graphene.ObjectType):
    key = graphene.String()
    value = graphene.String()

class Query(graphene.AbstractType):

    langs = graphene.List(LangChoiceType) # Changed to return a list
    def resolve_langs(self, info):
        # Creates a new LangChoiceType object by iterating terates over enum
        return [LangChoiceType(lang.name, lang.value) for lang in SWLangChoice]
```

The current documentation on graphene.Enum doesn't give a use case on their page, so I am not sure what it is for. Thus, I don't use it in my answer.

With the above code, following query and results are

```
query enum {
  langs {
    key
    value
  }
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "langs": [
      {
        "key": "PHP",
        "value": "PHP"
      },
      {
        "key": "PY",
        "value": "Python"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```